# JSF external redirect on commandButton action not working

Tags: jsf, redirect, jsf-2

Consider two web applications - A and B both hosted on different servers. On clicking a link in B, a HTTP request to made to A which responds back with the URL of A's page to be displayed to the user. Using its proxy, B hits the URL and A's page is displayed which has list of records. At this point the URL is like - https://B/proxy/A/context-root-A/page1.faces?un=1234 and everything works fine till here.

Now what I need is when a button is clicked in this JSF page1, page2 has to be displayed which shows record details.But,when the button is clicked the URL requested is like https://B/context-root-A/page2.faces?un=1234 and results in HTTP 404.

The original code just returned the path of page2 from A's context on the action of the commandButton. After watching some examples I thought of using External context redirect. But this redirect is not having any effect ending up giving the same HTTP 404.

The code snippet is:

```
<h:form name="myForm">
     <h:commandButton value="view" action="{myBean.view}"/>
</h:form>

public void view(){
   FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
       .redirect("https://B/proxy/A/context-root-A/page2.faces?un=1234");
}
```

I am also appending the id of record as request parameters to the redirect URL. Ignored it here to keep the question simple. Also tried `face-redirect=true` but still not working.

I have tried to best explain the environment in which I am facing the issue. Any help on what I am doing wrong will be highly appreciated.

Comment: So what you effectively asking is _"If I put in a wrong URL it gives me a 404. Can someone please explain why"_ (the URL that according to you results in a 404 **IS** the URL you put in the redirect)... Or am I missing something (it is after midnight here)?

Comment: Thanks for the edit @m00am. Nope. The redirect does not happen at all to the URL I am specifying. I would like to know why the redirect is not working. I checked the request being sent on button click using IE dev tools and see not redirect (HTTP 302) in it.

Comment: Can someone please assist with this issue.